# Does facebook make these sections readily available?

Tags: facebook, api

I'm looking to allow users to add certain sections of facebook to a webpage if they want.
I have a picture and have circled and numbered what I'm looking for.  I have looked through the getting started sections and the javascript SDK but I'm having a hard time.

The sections I'm looking for are the Top Bar (1)
The part above the who's online (2)
The who's online and chat (3)
The news feed (4)

Are these available in an iFrame I can just drop in?  If not, can I write code to get them and if I can code it myself can someone just point me in the right direction.

http://i46.tinypic.com/nmlzk5.png

Thanks for any and all help.

edit: I don't know how to make the picture show

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, because you would need the permission of all the user's friends to access that kind of information.

Comment: Does your answer apply to all 4 sections I was asking about? Basically I want a canvas style page, but with the ability to hide/show/move the items around.

Also, you said you "think". Does this mean you are not sure?

Comment: Chat API: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/
Graph API (for search in the top bar): http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/